# How to diplay in-memory byte array image with the Image component of React Native?

Tags: android, image, react-native

I'm developing an Android RN APP that displays images from a camera in real time. The received images are byte arrays, but it seems that RN's Image compoent doesn't support this type. I don't want to save the images because there are too many. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this package [`base64-js`](https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js).

It is written in **pure JS** and contains some cool methods as mentioned [here](https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js#methods).

- `byteLength` - Takes a base64 string and returns length of byte array
- `toByteArray` - Takes a base64 string and returns a byte array
- `fromByteArray` - Takes a byte array and returns a base64 string

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried base64 but the performance is really bad in my situation.